# Find the stationary points of $f(x,y)=x^2 (y+1)-2y$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-derivative

$$f(x,y)=x^2 (y+1)-2y$$

a. Find the stationary points of $f$ and establish their nature 
b. Find the absolute minimum and absolute maximum of $f$ on the set 
$$\mathbb{G}=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}: \sqrt{1+x^2} \le y \le 2\}$$

a.Now, I calculate the partial derivatives:
$$f_x (x,y)=2x(y+1)$$ $$f_y (x,y)=x^2-2$$
So, I have to solve this equation system:

\begin{cases}
2x(y+1)=0 \\
x^2-2=0 \\
\end{cases}

The stationary points are:

$$P_1=(\sqrt{2},-1) \qquad P_2=(-\sqrt{2},-1)$$

The Hessian matrix:

$$H(x,y)=\begin{bmatrix}2(y+1) & 2x  \\ 2x & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$H(\sqrt{2},-1)=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 2 \sqrt{2} \\ 2 \sqrt{2}  & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$H(-\sqrt{2},-1)=\begin{bmatrix}0 & -2 \sqrt{2} \\ -2 \sqrt{2}  & 0
 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\det H(\sqrt{2},-1)=\det H(-\sqrt{2},-1)=-8$$
$$\det H(\sqrt{2},-1)<0$$ So, $P_1$ and $P_2$ are saddle points

Is It correct?

How can I answer to b?

Thanks

Comment: Your solution for part  $a$ seems correct. For part $b$, do you have an idea about how to solve a constrained optimization problem ?

Comment: @Nizar I  used the method of Lagrange multipliers, but, in this case the 
bond is not an equation. In fact, I don't know how set a possible equations system for finding the constrained stationary points.

Comment: Indeed, the domain you are given is a closed domian. Usually in such cases the problem is divided into two parts, first study optimality on the open domain, then study optimality on the boundary of the domain. Note that when studying the problem on the boundary your  will be dealing with an equation ( for example here  $y=2$  and  $ y=\sqrt{x^2+1}$)